# Android MediaPlayer streaming video setSurface jump back

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, textureview

I m developing an Android app which can play streaming videos and navigate through the app with the video playing in background.

The video is playing on a Service and to watch the video i set the `MediaPlayer`'s surface to a `SurfaceTexture` of a `TextureView`. No problems here, this works fine.

The problem comes up when the user minimizes the player (without problem) and wants to re-open it. Here, when i re-set the Surface to the MediaPlayer the video jumps one or two seconds back and continues reproducing fine. Here is the code when i set the surface to the MediaPlayer:

```
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
      surfaceTexture = new Surface(surface);

      if (myMusicService != null) {
        myMusicService.getMediaPlayer().setSurface(surfaceTexture);
      }

}
```

I tried with a `SurfaceView` too (instead a `TextureView`) with the same result.

Any ideas?

Thanks,